# GWT Swipe between Pages / Panels

Tags: gwt, panel, swipe

I have a web app I'm creating, where I need to allow the user to swipe between pages. From what I've been researching you need to use MGWT (mobile Google web toolkit -- http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/)

Then you have to create a class that extends a Panel class and  implements MGWT's "HasTouchHandlers" interface:

(http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/mgwt/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/touch/TouchPanel.java?name=v1.0.0-alpha1)

Also your Panel should implement GWT's  AnimatedLayout interface (such as  LayoutPanel, DockLayoutPanel, and SplitLayoutPane), so you can natively slide the Panel after intercepting the touch event.

My question is can any one point me to a tutorial or example code on how to do this? Or how layout a GWT project in terms of
Panels? For example, if I have multiple pages in my app do I have multiple Panels?
thanks - Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer that you use **[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)** for swipe because it works without any issues on Android as well as iOS Browsers. The Implementation will also work on 3rd party browsers like Diigo or Dolphin. With this you i think you can completely avoid using the mgwt API.

Answer (score 4):

mgwt now has support for swipes. There is a swipe recognizer as well as a swipe panel:

See it in action:
http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#CarouselPlace:

Here is the code:
http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/Carousel.java

Comment: Hey Daniel, are you using CSS3 Transitions in MGWT?

Comment: URL have changed. To see it in action : http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#CarouselPlace: and to see the code : https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/carousel/Carousel.java

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it yourself by adding *implements TouchStartHandler, TouchMoveHandler, TouchEndHandler* to you class and handling the events and store what has happened. If you have moved more than X between start and end it's a swipe.